# Displacement and Bump problem?

Tags: shaders, displacement, bump

total noob here,
Following the ol' donut tutorial.
Ive come to the texture shading section and trying to get my displacement and bump to look like the tutorial.
Ive attached a couple pics of what Mine looks like compare to his.
blenderguru has a nice, very soft cloudy look and mine looks like a plastic toy

Any ideas what I did wrong?
Thank you for looking,
Here is mine:
[image]

Here is his:

[image]

Comment: Are you rendering with Cycles? This looks like an EEVEE result

Comment: Freeze the video at 6:15, you see he has a subsurface value of .105 and and a pink subsurface color. You have the color, but your subsurface is at 0.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think that did it!!